# ggplot2: using square brackets and superscript in axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot where each axis has been log10 transformed. For one of my axis titles I would like to use both a square bracket (`[]`) and a superscript. How can I do this?

Example Data

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 20))
colnames(df)[1:2] <- c('x','y')
df$x <- rnorm(20,1000,100)
df$y <- rnorm(20,1000,100)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(log_x = log10(x),
         log_y = log10(y))
```

Here is an example of the figure I am trying to make. I need to know how to make the `-2` on the x-axis superscripted.

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = log_x, y = log_y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = expression(log[10]~"[Area (m^-2)]"),
       y = expression(log[10]~"[ Time Variable (months)]")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

Comment: You need to have the `^-2` part outside of the string. Try something like `x = expression(log[10]~"[Disturbance Area"~ (m^-2) ~"]")`

Answer (score 0):

@MrFlick response provides the correct answer, see below.

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = log_x, y = log_y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = expression(log[10]~"[Area"~ (m^-2) ~"]"),
       y = expression(log[10]~"[ Time Variable (months)]")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]